# Matplotlib animate does not update tick labels

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to modify and example by making the animation run on increasing x values. I want update the x axis tick labels to update according to the x values.

I am trying to use the animation features (specifically FuncAnimation) in 1.2. I can set the xlimit but the tick labels are not updating. I tried explicitly setting the tick labels too and this does not work.

I saw this: [Animating matplotlib axes/ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299943/animating-matplotlib-axes-ticks) and
I tried to adjust the bbox in animation.py but it did not work. I am fairly new to matplotlib and do not know enough about what is really going on to address this issue so I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

```
"""
Matplotlib Animation Example

author: Jake Vanderplas
email: vanderplas@astro.washington.edu
website: http://jakevdp.github.com
license: BSD
Please feel free to use and modify this, but keep the above information. Thanks!
"""

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(i, i+2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    ax.set_xlim(i, i+2)

    return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                           frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: There is a better answer for your question, see the edit.

Answer (score 9):

See [Animating matplotlib axes/ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299943/animating-matplotlib-axes-ticks), [python matplotlib blit to axes or sides of the figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844223/python-matplotlib-blit-to-axes-or-sides-of-the-figure), and [Animated title in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558096/animated-title-in-matplotlib)

The simple answer is remove `blit=True`

```
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                           frames=200, interval=20)
```

If you have `blit = True` only artists that have changed are re-drawn (rather than re-drawing all of the artists) which makes the rendering more efficient.  Artists are marked as changed if they are returned from the update-function (in this case `animate`).  The other detail is that the artists must be with in the axes bounding box with the way the code works in `animation.py`.  See one of the links at the top for how to deal with this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This redraws everything though. I want the gridlines and ticks to be fixed. I want to be able to change the text on the x axis labels

Comment: @Jared do you mean the labels on the ticks, or the label on the axis?